# Why does Zend Framework 2 use application/x-www-form-urlencoded for put request?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, postman

Why do I have to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` option when I try to test the PUT method in Zend Framework 2 on Postman?

```
/*
Use multipart/form-data for testing.
*/
public function create($data)
{
    $form = new AlbumForm();
    $album = new Album();
    $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
    $form->setData($data);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $album->exchangeArray($form->getData());
        $id = $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album);
    }

    return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $album->extract(),
    ));
}

/*
Use application/x-www-form-urlencoded for testing.
*/
public function update($id, $data)
{
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $album = $this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id);
    $form  = new AlbumForm();
    $form->bind($album);
    $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
    $form->setData($data);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $id = $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($form->getData());
    }

    return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $album->extract(),
    ));
}
```

I will get this result if I got for `form-data` option,

```
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundaryP9erwzQtIaB0m0tr
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "title"

bla bla bla bla xxx
------WebKitFormBoundaryP9erwzQtIaB0m0tr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="artist"

xxx xxx
------WebKitFormBoundaryP9erwzQtIaB0m0tr--

)
```

I don't understand why Zend2 expects that. Any ideas? What are the advantages using `x-www-form-urlencoded` over `form-data` - in Zend2 context then?

Can I configure that somewhere in Zend2 to use `form-data` option for PUT method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that form-data doesn't work nicely in PHP with PUT requests. This has nothing to do with ZF2, this is also the case with Symfony2 or Slim, for example. For POST requests, this is not a problem, because PHP has the internals parsing the data for you and providing it in `$_POST`.

The case here is that parsing form-data is not trivial. The basic part of boundaries and splitting the multiple key/values is easy. It becomes harder with binary data and especially all edge conditions that exists. Not speaking of incredibly large bodies where you'd rather want stream based parsing than loading the whole string in memory.

So, try using urlencoded bodies, or write your own form-data parser. Those are, unfortunately, the only two options.

Comment: `try using urlencoded bodies, or write your own form-data parser.` any examples and guides that I can start with?

Comment: A very small example, not incorporating all possible results can be found here: http://www.chlab.ch/blog/archives/php/manually-parse-raw-http-data-php Another more complex one is the rejected PR in symfony, with all discussion about why this isn't such great idea: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10381#issuecomment-38717986